# Deploying a Message Driven Bean to JBoss Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am trying to deploy a WAR to my JBoss Server, and the WAR has a dependency on an EJB module. When I try to deploy the WAR I get the following error:

```
Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.resource.spi.InvalidPropertyException: Destination is mandatory
```

My ejb-jar has:

```
        <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>LeagueListenerMDB</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.club.ejb.LeagueListenerMDB</ejb-class>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>java:/topic/ejava/projects/contests</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
    </message-driven>
```

My EJB is annotated with:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/topic/ejava/projects/contests"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue = "ContestAction = 'ContestScheduled' OR "
        + "ContestAction = 'ContestRescheduled' OR "
        + "ContestAction = 'ContestCanceled'"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
```

})

I have the destination in the annotation and the ejb-jar, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
```

and I haven't ever used java: prefix with MDB destination, so this might get it working as well:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
    propertyValue = "topic/ejava/projects/contests"),
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, after renaming the MDB to another name (to avoid duplicate jndi entries with the same Name "testQueue") and modifying the ejb-jar.xml, it works:

```
package test;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSDestinationDefinition;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@JMSDestinationDefinition(name = "NewMessageBean", interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue", resourceAdapter = "jmsra", destinationName = "testQueue")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "willBeOverwrittenInDeploymentDescriptor")
})
public class NewMessageBean implements MessageListener {

    public NewMessageBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    }

}
```

The ActivationConfigProperty destination is still needed, otherwise an exception gets thrown in the deployment phase.

The destination-value gets overwritten by the following ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>NewMessageBean</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>test.NewMessageBean</ejb-class>

            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>/jms/testClientQueue</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

With this ejb-jar.xml, the mdb connects to /jms/testClientQueue